# My 6-year-old daughter's undies get stuck to her skin. How to solve this problem?

Tags: primary-schooler, clothes

My girl is 6 years old. Often, when she pulls her panties down, they seem to get kind of stuck to her skin, often between her legs. This is pretty embarrassing for her, considering she just started school, and needs to remove her panties after gymnastic class, to shower.

She says that they are not too small. It also happen when they are dry. She mostly gets them off, on the second try. It happens with most panties, so not just one pair.

What could cause this, or what could solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same problem when you try to help her, then they perhaps are too small, no matter what she says.

I'd be tempted to suggest that is the issue anyway, she has not yet figured out the best way to remove them, or they are slightly too small to get them off easily.

Indeed, I'm not sure why this is embarrassing - if it takes a bit of shuffling to get them off, why does this cause issues? It seems the sort of thing other kids wouldn't be aware of unless she tells them.

In any case, try the next size up, and the problem may solve itself, or see if she can show you how she is trying to get them off, and you may be able to indicate a better technique.

Comment: Some of them might be a little bit to small for her , but she says that the fabric gets kinda stuck to her skin, when she pulls them off.
Guess she takes off them like most other girls do, she puts her hands on her hips and pulls them off, but i do guess there is some better techniques as well, that she can try.
Guess we should buy some new panties for her, to see if they work better :)
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea might be to use a little powder - they sell small travel size powders - this will prevent the panties from getting stuck.

Comment: there are health concerns about extended use of talcum powder, if that was what you were meaning